# Unable to add product to a custom collection

Tags: shopify

Using the shopify gem I'm trying to add a product to a custom collection.

```
c = ShopifyAPI::CustomCollection.first(:title => "Man")
p = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(95448374)
```

If I try:

```
c.products << p
c.save
=> true
```

But the product is not added to the custom collection.

I also tried

```
p.collections << c
p.save
=> true
```

But still the product is not added to the collection...why?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Augusto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer lies in the source:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/resources/product.rb#L30

You have to use the add_to_collection or add_product methods because these create a Collect object, which is what we use to associate a product and collection.

Comment: Yay!  Thank you so much for such a quick and accurate reply!